# How to create 'Lifetime' subscription on app store?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I have an app on app store that includes 'Monthly, Annual, 6 Months' subscription models.
I want change 6 Months to Lifetime. So I know, I can't delete any subscription model. But how can I add lifetime subscription model on app store. Do I select non-consumable subs. on app store connects.
Thanks for helps.[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a lifetime subscription is a non-consumable in-app purchase.